# How do i shuffle a track list with an array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, bluej

im trying to shuffle music tracks with the collections im unsure of on how to do this.

```
public void Shuffle()
{
   Collections ArrayList<Track>;

}
```

what i started with ^

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_shuffle.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Comment: There is a static method on the `Collections`-class called `shuffle`. Try passing your list to that method.

Comment: What you started with isn't nowhere near syntactically correct code. Do you know how to create, fill and use an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Collections.shuffle(List list)

More to read:
[Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
public class Random {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> teamList=Arrays.asList("Ananaya", "Mike","James", "Shashwat");

            Collections.shuffle(teamList);
            int counter=0;
            for (String value:teamList){

                System.out.println("The build schedule for week "+ ++counter + " is to be done by "+value);

            }       
        }
    }
```